# Using '/' with long double?

Tags: c, double, precision

I am trying to understand why using '/' with long double in the following way leads to a 0.000000 value while the same code with double does not

```
double d = (double)total_results / (double)total_points;
```

Gives the value 0.785403 but

```
long double d = (long double)total_results / (long double)total_points;
```

Gives the value 0.000000.  I am trying to get the most accurate value for 'total_results / total_points'

EDIT: In the end the error was simply that I was outputting it using '%f' instead of '%Lf'

Before

```
printf("Running on %d thread(s), results is %f.\n", NUM_THREADS, d);
```

After

```
printf("Running on %d thread(s), results is %Lf.\n", NUM_THREADS, d);
```

Comment: What are the types of total_results and total_points ? Casting them to `long double` might change the accessed value in a wrong way

Comment: Ernest Friedman-Hill's answer indicates you should, with problems that can, always post a minimal working program that exhibits your problem.

Comment: @Eregrith If casting to `long double` would cause a problem, casting to `double` would cause even bigger a problem! Let's just assume it's OK; that total_result and total_points are numbers.

Comment: Why did this receive 7 upvotes? It isn't a good question, since the line causing the problem wasn't even included in the question. Please edit the question so that it includes the printf() lines and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is obviously just a guess, but how are you outputting the results? If you're using `printf` with the wrong field specifier, printing an erroneous zero is definitely a possible result. Using g++, I tried "%lf" and got "-2.0000" when I should have gotten "0.75". The right specifier is "%Lf", with a capital L.

Comment: Yes, or `%llf`, that works too. (under gcc 4.3, Linux at least)

Comment: This was the problem. I was using '%f'. Thank you

Comment: @MrLister: That comment is not helpful; it's just teaching OP the **wrong** way to do something and seemingly have it work, when the **right** answer has already been given.

Comment: @MrLister because it's not mandated by the standard that `%llf` can be used to print `long double`s, the standard specifies the `L` modifier, so anything else may work on some compilers but is non-portable.

Comment: It works on many compilers, but I see now that it's a GNU extension and that the standard proscribes `L`. Oh well. Off to edit all my programs!

Comment: C11 7.21.6.1/7: `ll (ell-ell) Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long long int or unsigned long long int argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a long long int argument.` /--/ `L Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to a long double argument.`

Comment: Everything that isn't compatible with what I posted from the standard is icky non-standard goo that shouldn't be used. GCC extensions in general should not be used in production code.